# Animate vertical line with scatter and circle - matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I am trying to animate a vertical line along with a scatter and circle. I can get the scatter and circle working but not the vertical line. If possible, I'd also like the vertical line to not plot outside the radius of the circle. I can follow up on this though.

I'll comment out the function in `animate` in regards to the line so it runs. But when applying the animated line, it doesn't work.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import animation

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (8,8))
ax.set_xlim(-20,20)
ax.set_ylim(-20,20)
ax.grid(False)

df = pd.DataFrame({   
    'Time' : [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3],             
    'X2' : [0,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,0,0,0],
    'Y2' : [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],                    
    })

moving_x = np.array(df.groupby(['Time'])['X2'].apply(list))
moving_y = np.array(df.groupby(['Time'])['Y2'].apply(list))

# scatter moving
moving_point = ax.scatter(moving_x[0], moving_y[0], c = 'black', marker = 'x')

# Array of immediate congestion radius coordinates
radius = df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['Time','X2', 'Y2'])[['X2', 'Y2']].values

# Plot immediate congestion radius
circle = plt.Circle(radius[0], 10, color = 'black', fill = False)

# Add radius to plot
ax.add_patch(circle)

t = df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['Time','X2'])[['X2']].values

line1 = ax.axvline(t[0], ls = '--', color = 'black', lw = 1, zorder = 10)

def animate(i) :

    circle.center = (radius[i,0], radius[i,1])

    # Animate vertical line
    #line1.set_data([i, i],[0,t])
    
    moving_point.set_offsets(np.c_[moving_x[0+i], moving_y[0+i]])


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate,  np.arange(0,2), blit = False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to set `blit=True` so that you don't have to redraw things since the axes have not changed. I have also avoided the use of `axvline` as shown below:

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import animation

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (8,8))
ax.set_xlim(-20,20)
ax.set_ylim(-20,20)
ax.grid(False)

df = pd.DataFrame({   
    'Time' : [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3],             
    'X2' : [0,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,0,0,0],
    'Y2' : [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],                    
    })

moving_x = np.array(df.groupby(['Time'])['X2'].apply(list))
moving_y = np.array(df.groupby(['Time'])['Y2'].apply(list))

# scatter moving
moving_point = ax.scatter(moving_x[0], moving_y[0], c = 'black', marker = 'x')

# Array of immediate congestion radius coordinates
radius = df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['Time','X2', 'Y2'])[['X2', 'Y2']].values

# Plot immediate congestion radius
circle = plt.Circle(radius[0], 10, color = 'black', fill = False)

# Add radius to plot
ax.add_patch(circle)

t = df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['Time','X2'])[['X2']].values

#line1 = ax.axvline(t[0], ls = '--', color = 'black', lw = 1, zorder = 10)
line1, = ax.plot([], [], ls='--', color='black',lw=1, zorder=10,animated=True)
def animate(i) :
    circle.center = (radius[i,0], radius[i,1])

    # Animate vertical line
    line1.set_data([radius[i,0], radius[i,0]],[radius[i,1]-10,radius[i,1]+10])
    
    moving_point.set_offsets(np.c_[moving_x[0+i], moving_y[0+i]])
    return circle, line1, moving_point

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate,  np.arange(0,2), blit = True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm on a Mac and it get's funny with blit. This code works though. Just removed the animated function in the line plot.